# IE 11 Issue: Error: Syntax error Evaluating http://localhost:5000/app/app.module.js, Evaluating http://localhost:5000/app/main.js

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

[image]I am working on angular2 in visual studio 2015. I got in to issues where Chrome, Fire fox and Edge are displaying the content but IE 11 failed with the error in the title.
my package.json is

```html
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^4.0.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.3.0",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.4.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"    
  }
}
```

My gulpfile.js is

```html
/*
This file in the main entry point for defining Gulp tasks and using Gulp plugins.
Click here to learn more. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=518007
*/

var gulp = require('gulp');
var libs = './wwwroot/lib/';


gulp.task('restore:core-js', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/core-js/client/*.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(libs + 'core-js'));
});

gulp.task('restore:zone.js', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/*.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(libs + 'zone.js'));
});

gulp.task('restore:reflect-metadata', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/reflect-metadata/reflect.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(libs + 'reflect-metadata'));
});

gulp.task('restore:systemjs', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/systemjs/dist/*.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(libs + 'systemjs'));
});

gulp.task('restore:rxjs', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(libs + 'rxjs'));
});

gulp.task('restore:angular-in-memory-web-api', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/**/*.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(libs + 'angular-in-memory-web-api'));
});

gulp.task('restore:angular', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(libs + '@angular'));
});

gulp.task('default', function () {
    // place code for your default task here
});

gulp.task('restore:bootstrap', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/**/*.*'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(libs + 'bootstrap'));
});

gulp.task('restore', [
    'restore:core-js',
    'restore:zone.js',
    'restore:reflect-metadata',
    'restore:systemjs',
    'restore:rxjs',
    'restore:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    'restore:angular',
    'restore:bootstrap'
]);
```

My tsconfig.js is

```html
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "rootDir": "app",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

my systemjs.config.js is

```html
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            'npm:': 'lib/'
        },
        map: {
            app: 'app',

            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js",
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api'
        },

        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

my typings.json is

```html
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.9.0+20170324193834",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#7.0.0+20170322231424"
  }
}
```

My layout page header section

```html
    
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/core-js/shim.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/zone.js/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/reflect-metadata/reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/systemjs/system.src.js"></script>


    <script src="~/js/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(
            function (err) {
                console.error(err)
            })
    </script>
```

app.module.ts

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'mna',
    template: `<div><h1>{{message}}</h1></div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    message: string = "hello angular2 from component";
}
```

main.ts

```html
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

This an asp.net core project.
Your insights are highly appreciated.

Comment: what is the error says add a screenshot

Comment: Syntax error:  Evaluating http://localhost:5000/app/app.module.js 
  Evaluating http://localhost:5000/app/main.js

Comment: syntax error is straight forward to which line it points too?

Comment: I have added a screenshot to my post. Please check.

Comment: you have error in your systemjs fix it

Comment: What is the error? Can you please explain it?

Comment: Can you point out what the error is?